# the app crashes when I click the button to change activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I want to change activity by clicking a button, I saw a tutorial on YouTube but when I click the button on the main screen the app crashes and makes me exit

Process: com.example.notestry, PID: 10514
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.notestry/com.example.notestry.CrewNovaNota}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared ?

code:
[image: code:]

Comment: include the manifest and the activity / fragment (the button) code, otherwise we may just suggest to check if your activity (the one you want to navigate to) is declared in the AndroidManifest or make sure your intent doesn't contain a spelling mistake or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, all of your activities need to be declared in the application's manifest file so that they can be seen by Android. The error is complaining that you are attempting to use some activity that Android cannot see/find. You can fix it by declaring the activity in your manifest file.

In your manifest file, inside the

```
<application>

</application>
```

tag, try adding the following:

```
<activity android:name=".CrewNovaNota"/>
```

This should fix the error.

Good luck! Let me know how it goes :D